# WPF change background of a control with an attached property

Tags: c#, wpf, attached-properties, brushes

i need to change the background of labels and buttons when a boolean variable is true (back to default color on false). so i wrote an attached property. it looks like this so far:

```
public class BackgroundChanger : DependencyObject
{
    #region dependency properties
    // status
    public static bool GetStatus(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(StatusProperty);
    }
    public static void SetStatus(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(StatusProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Status",
                     typeof(bool), typeof(BackgroundChanger), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnStatusChange));

    #endregion

    private static void OnStatusChange(DependencyObject obj,  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        var element = obj as Control;
        if (element != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                element.Background = Brushes.LimeGreen;
            else
                element.Background = default(Brush);
        }
    }
}
```

and i use it like this:

```
<Label CustomControls:BackgroundChanger.Status="{Binding test}" />
```

it works fine. when the according variable `test` is set in the viewmodel, the backgroundcolor changes to `LimeGreen`.

**my question:**

the color `LimeGreen` is hard coded. i would like to set that color (and the default color as well) in the XAML as well. so i can decide between which two colors the background switches. how can i do that?

Comment: How about using one more attached property to specify color when `Status` is true? Or to make `Status` a `Brush` type?

Comment: i am struggeling with making one (ore two) more properties. how do i use them in `OnStatusChanged`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple attached properties. Accessing them is easy, there are static `Get..` and `Set..` methods, to which you supply `DependencyObject` which attached property value you want to operate.

```
public class BackgroundChanger : DependencyObject
{
    // make property Brush Background
    // type "propdp", press "tab" and complete filling

    private static void OnStatusChange(DependencyObject obj,  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        var element = obj as Control;
        if (element != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                element.Background = GetBrush(obj); // getting another attached property value
            else
                element.Background = default(Brush);
        }
    }
}
```

In xaml it will look like

```
<Label CustomControls:BackgroundChanger.Status="{Binding test}"
    CustomControls:BackgroundChanger.Background="Red"/>
```

Comment: ok, that works. but how do i set these properties now in the view in xaml?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a DataTrigger instead?

```
<Style x:Key="FilePathStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=AddButton, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEBF7E1" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=AddButton, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

.
.
.
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource FilePathStyle}" x:Name="filePathControl" Width="300" Height="25" Margin="5" Text="{Binding SelectedFilePath}" />
```

Comment: at the moment i am working with datatrigger. but writing all these lines on every control i need that functionality?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. These controls are leveraging the style where they all can derive their behavior in one place (i.e. style).